# Assumptions when using scikit-learn DPGMM

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, bayesian

I have been using scikit-learn's Dirichlet Process gaussian mixture model to cluster my dataset. And I have been using this excellent tutorial for this purpose : http://blog.echen.me/2012/03/20/infinite-mixture-models-with-nonparametric-bayes-and-the-dirichlet-process/

In the end, the author uses a dataset that clusters food items using their nutritional values (i.e- total fat, vitamin D, vitamin C etc) as features. Before the implementation of the algorithm, the author normalizes these features. What is the importance of the normalization ? Does every single item in the dataset need to have a feature set that is a gaussian distribution ? Is that an underlying assumption ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Dirichlet process Gaussian mixture model is the infinite limit of a Gaussian mixture model and therefore assumes Gaussian distribution of your data. Recap the generative process of a Gaussian mixture model. The formulation of a Dirichlet process mixture model itself however is independent of the observation distribution.

Normalisation of the data, e.g. z-score, is not necessary if you parametrize the base distribution of the model properly. If this is not possible in the implementation you use than normalisation is required.